Hardness of the Metric TSP for the Maximum Metric
I know that it is not too difficult to construct a metric to show that the metric TSP is NP-hard. The typical example is (1,2)-TSP.
I also know that Papadimitriou has shown that Euclidean TSP is NP-hard. But I could not find anything about the hardness of the (2D) TSP with the maximum metric. Concretely, the problem is as follows:
Given a set of points $P \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, find a tour $T = ((x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_{|P|}, y_{|P|}))$ that contains each point $p \in P$ exactly once such that the tour cost
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{|P|-1} \max \{ |x_i - x_{i+1}|, |y_i - y_{i+1}| \}
$$
is minimized.
Is this problem NP-hard?

It is NP-hard, here's a proof.
In [1], it is shown that the Hamiltonian path problem is NP-hard on induced subgraphs of the infinite grid (i.e. graphs that are defined by taking a set of integer points in 2D and connecting two points if their distance is 1).
From this, it follows that the 2D TSP with the Manhattan metric (i.e. $dist = |x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$) is NP-hard, as such graph has a Hamiltonian path if and only if we have such tour with cost $n-1$.
Now, to reduce the Manhattan metric to the max metric, we can simply use the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x-y)$. In particular, it holds that $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2| = max(|x_1+y_1-x_2-y_2|, |x_1-y_1-x_2+y_2|)$. This finishes the reduction.
[1] "Hamilton Paths in Grid Graphs" Alon Itai, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Jayme Luiz Szwarcfiter, SICOMP, 1982, https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0211056
